# Bootstrap Multi select search clear button click event not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am using bootstrap multi-selector with search enabled option.

[image]

I am trying to unselect all selected items on click of X button. But i am not able to handle click event for this button.

**Please help or suggest a better way to do this.**

Here is sample code:

```
<select id="multiselect-users" name="users[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">User1</option>
    <option value="2">User2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#multiselect-users').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true
 });
  // .multiselect-clear-filter is X button class. This button is part of bootstrape-multiselect if you enable filter
 $(document).on('click', '.multiselect-clear-filter', function(){

    // not working :(
    alert('test');
 });
</script>
```

[image]

I want to unselect all selected items on click of this X button.

Comment: And your code is?

Comment: @z3nth10n code added :)

Answer (score 0):

What you a really expecting is that when you click on a `select option` an alert is displayed.

But the name of this event is not called 'click' is called 'changed':

```js
     $(document).on('change', '#multiselect-users', function(){
    
     // woking :)
     alert('test');
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiselect-users" name="users[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">User1</option>
      <option value="2">User2</option>
    </select>
```

Also, you should add this event to the `select` tag not to `.multiselect-clear-filter`.

I have to say something about the:

```
 $('#multiselect-users').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true
 });
```

part. And is that `change` event doesn't work when this is enabled. But I think maybe this function is from another library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, actually i want to unselect all selected items on click of X button of search box. See the last screenshot of my post

Comment: But, alert is shown when you click this button? You should edit your answer and show the implementation of the `.multiselect-clear-filter` tag.

Comment: Yes, .multiselect-clear-filter is X button class. I checked it by inspect element. Actually X button is automatically appended when you set enableFiltering to true for searching.

Comment: Try to change `$(document)` to `$(<selector of the textbox>)` and instead of calling `click` event change it to `keydown` and inside put what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this option also

```
 $('#multiselect-users').multiselect({
        includeFilterClearBtn:true
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$('.multiselect-clear-filter').click(function () {
    $('#myDropDown option:selected').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('selected', false);
    })
    $('#myDropDown').multiselect('refresh');
});
```

**NOTE: Do not include this inside** `$(document).Ready()`

Comment: jQuery's ready is all lowercase. Also, why not include this code after the dom has loaded. If the scripts are loaded in the <head> then the selected will not find the elements and will therefore not apply the listener to anything.

On the other hand, if you include this script on the bottom of the <body>, the dom ready should not be necessary.